# Remove text between tags using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

How to remove text between br tags , using regexp

```
<br />var j=; var g=; g+=G;j+=30006;g+=a;g+=u;g+=l;g+=t;<br />
```

"var" and ";" is always exist, but other words and symbols may vary, something like this:

```
<br />var e=; var x=; x+=tos;x+=ах,;<br />
```

etc...

these lines appear in random order:

```
<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />var j=; var g=; g+=G;j+=30006;g+=a;g+=u;g+=l;g+=t;<br /> Donec condimentum neque quis magna consectetur ut aliquam quam dictum. Fusce sed elit purus, lobortis tincidunt libero.<br />Nunc ultrices augue non augue tristique in aliquet urna adipiscing.<br /><br />var ... ;<br />
```

thanks!

Comment: To clarify: you want the output to be `<br /><br />` correct?

Comment: What is the output that you are looking for? In both examples do you just want `<br /><br />`?

Comment: Why isn't the question more along the lines of: "I am given this text from X and need to remove a part of it to put in Y. How can I do this". By asking "How to remove text between br tags , *using regexp*" you'll get the mandatory "don't do" answers that link to *the regex question*. It's sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp you want would be

```
<br\s\/?>.*?var.*?;.*?<br\s\/?>
```

and just replace the output by `<br /><br />`.

Comment: I am afraid my solution will not work properly, e.g., test it on string: `<br />wwwwwwwwwwwww <br />var j=; var g=; g+=G;j+=30006;g+=a;g+=u;g+=l;g+=t;<br />something like this<br />wwww var e=; var x=; x+=tos;x+=ах,;<br />` it will aslo delete the part `<br />wwwwwwwwwwwww <br />`. I am working on a workaround for this issure.

Comment: If you know that you do not have any other tags inside then this, `<br\s\/?>[^<]+var[^<]*?;[^<]*?<br\s\/?>`, would work. But you would need to know that no other tags are in the text you want to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the output `<br /><br />`, you don't need regular expressions:

```
$result = "<br /><br />";
```

It's just a constant!

Comment: if you have a full html document, and you'd like to remove all the content between the br tags, you're code whont work .

Comment: @poelinca: I know. That's why I commented on the question asking for info about where this text comes from and where it goes to.

Comment: a have many similar strings, task - find all these lines, and remove content (sorry for ugly english)

Comment: i saw you're comment but i still think you should have waited for a reply from OP as the question is rather vague you can't tell if you actualy posted a good solution to the problem or not .

Comment: @Vadim: and the input is well-formed with always an even number of <br/>'s? Or do you have to deal with odd <br/>'s (like `<br/>foo<br/>bar<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

if count of `<br />` elements vary you can use `substr_count()` to count `<br />` elements and then output same amount separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it for a whole text and by pairs of `<br/>` you can do something like that :

```
$str = 'test0 <br />var j=; var g=; g+=G;j+=30006;g+=a;g+=u;g+=l;g+=t;<br /> test1 <br /> test2';
$result = preg_replace('`<br */>.*?<br */>`s','<br/><br/>',$str);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: You regexp will not work if he had `<br>` instead of `<br/>`. Moreover, it will also not work on the string like this `<br /> <br />var j=; var g=; g+=G;j+=30006;g+=a;g+=u;g+=l;g+=t;<br />something like this<br />var e=; var x=; x+=tos;x+=ах,;<br />` as it will remove text that was ment to remain.